# Bind values dynamically to TextView properties in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am designing a table with different columns filled with data, from an SAP OData backend, into textviews.

The design and semanticColor properties of the `TextView` are values received as a string. However loading fails with an error message: "String XY cannot be interpreted as design" // "..as semantic color" after binding in the following way..

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text : "{MyBackendElement}",
    textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center,
    design : "{Class}",
    semanticColor : "{FontClass},
  }),
  visible : true,
}));
```

If I put in the design and semantic color directly, everything works fine, but how can I make this from my service? which data type does it need? Is it possible to transform the string defined in brackets {} for design and semantic color??

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text : "{MyBackendElement}", 
    textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center,
    design : sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign.Bold,
    semanticColor : sap.ui.commons.TextViewColor.Critical,
  }),
  visible : true,
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is partly in your question itself, the properties `design` and `semanticColor` only accept values of type `sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign` and `sap.ui.commons.TextViewColor`.

However, as in your case you would be binding "strings" to these properties, you would need to **ensure** that the string is *same* as the last word of the possible list of values for the accepted types.

For example,

`sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign` accepts

- sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign.Bold
- sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign.Italic

and so on. Therefore, you need to bring in "Bold" or "Italic" from your OData and bind it to the properties. Same goes for `sap.ui.commons.TextViewColor`

In your code snippet,

`oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text : "{MyBackendElement}",
    textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center,
    design : "{Class}",
    semanticColor : "{FontClass},
  }),
  visible : true,
}));`

'Class' would have values "Bold", "Italic"... and 'FontClass' would have "Critical", "Default"...

The list of allowed values for

1. `sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign` is [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign.html)
2. `sap.ui.commons.TextViewColor` is [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.TextViewColor.html)

Comment: do you know if this is adaptable to links in a table? I can't find design or semanticColor as attributes for links. Any idea?

Comment: unfortunately looking at the documentation it doesn't look like it exists for links

Comment: I thought about: var oLink = new sap.ui.commons.Link({ text : "{Element}", }); and then oLink.addStyleClass("{Class}"); but this does not work, it adds a class called {Class} and not the content ... how to I get the content in here during initalization?

Comment: @zyrex the binding would only work if it is a property of the control, in this case it is not. And the approach you have tried wouldn't work as well. The addStyleClass method adds a css style class from a .css file that you have provided in your project.

Comment: the addStyleClass would work it is a different style class depending on my string from the service, but its always the same..

Comment: ya thats because "{class}" wouldn't work inside addStyleClass. It would only work as .addStyleClass("class") where 'class' is a style class defined in a style.css file